# Doctrine ORM : Calculated related entity count in one shot

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've a User entity and a Product entity.

```
class User{
     /*
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="User")
     */
     private $Products;
}

class Product{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="Products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $User;

}
```

Now I'm trying to display a html table of users, but I want to show each user's product count too.
By using following code I'm able to obtain the users objects.

```
  $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

  $qb->select('usr')
        ->from('User', 'usr');
  $query = $qb->getQuery();
```

But I don't know how to get the products count in one shot. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should really create a repository class for your entities if you want to create custom queries. Then you can simply run that query by injecting the entity repository as a service wherever you need it and then running the query method.

Second, you need to return a result from a doctrine query to retrieve anything from the database. If you want to determine the count of the objects returned, simply do this:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('usr')
   ->from('User', 'usr');
$query = $qb->getQuery();

$count = count($query->getResult());
```

A doctrine query will return an array of objects matching your query. If you just want to return a count of the matching records, try something like this:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('count(id)')
   ->from('User', 'usr');
$query = $qb->getQuery();

$count = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Or to just get a count of Product objects for that user, from within the User repository class:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('usr');
$qb->select('count(p.id)')
   ->from('usr.Products', 'p');

return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: Yes I'm using repository classes. Actually I want to get the each user's product count, while obtaining all users. Not the total users count.

Comment: Since you've mapped products to users as a OneToMany association, doctrine should do the heavy lifting for you. `$User->getProducts()` should give you an array of `Product` objects and `count($User->getProducts())` should give you a count of those objects.

Comment: If you don't want the overhead of retrieving product objects just to determine a count, then yeah you'll need a custom query in your entity repository. I'll update the post above to include an example.

Comment: Try that. I'm just working off memory atm, so let me know if that works. Since you already have an association between your entities, it simplifies the query. Otherwise, you can do a `->from('User', 'usr')->innerJoin('usr.Persons', 'p')` ... I hope you get the idea.